# How can I call a ReactJS function in another ReactJS function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my reactJS constructor, I have three functions defined.

```
    this.play = this.play.bind(this);
    this.pause = this.pause.bind(this);
    this.stop=this.stop.bind(this);
```

In my stop() function, I am trying to use the this.pause function,

```
stop() {

    this.state.audioList[this.state.currSongKey].currentTime = 0;
    this.pause

}
```

But this doesn't work. How am I supposed to use it in my different function?

**EDIT**

```
play(){

        this.state.audioList[this.state.currSongKey].play()

      }



stop() {

        this.state.audioList[this.state.currSongKey].currentTime = 0;
        this.state.audioList[this.state.currSongKey].pause();
        // Actually want to call the pause() method here, not the pause() provided by HTML5 Audio which is what im using currently

    }

pause(){

    this.state.audioList[this.state.currSongKey].pause();
}
```

They all only work when I try to set them as onClick events for buttons, but does not work when I try to use it in another function.

Comment: use `()` to call a function, like this: `this.pause()`, marking to close the ques "Simple typo".

Comment: this has remotely nothing to do with react in general

Comment: I was asking because it didn't work even with the bracket.

Comment: What are you doing in the pause function, can you post that code as well and what doesn't work when you use `this.pause()`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri edited my question. thanks